# How can I put limits on a variable type int in python?

Tags: python

I need to put a limit when entering a number for a certain attribute, how can I do that?

```py
class Escuelas:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cod_provincia = 0:1
```

Comment: You can't, the Python type system does not support this. This would be "dependent" types or "refinement types".

Comment: Check out `@property` and or `property()`

Comment: Wait, are you asking about *type annotations*?

Comment: @juanpa-arrivillaga Maybe I don't understand the question correctly but this seems exactly the kind of thing setters are for. Unless this is a type system question rather that a limit on setting values.

Comment: @JonSG well, the question is unclear to me at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

**You should use `Encapsulation` principle.**

```
class Escuelas:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__cod_provincia = 0

    @property
    def cod_provincia(self):
        return self.__cod_provincia

    @cod_provincia.setter
    def cod_provincia(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, int) and value in (0, 1):
            self.__cod_provincia = value
        else:
            raise ValueError('Not Valid Code!')
```

> if you want set value in specific range you just use `range(start, end)` instead of the tuple `(0, 1)` in setter method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somewhere in your code, you need something like below:

```
if self.cod_provincia not in [0, 1]:
    raise ValueError("Entrada de código no válida.")
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to force an int value to be within a certain range when it is set.

Is this what you require?

```
class Escuelas:
    def __init__(self):
        self.intValue = None
        self.upperLimit = 100
    def setIntValue(self,newValue):
        self.intValue = self.upperLimit if newValue>self.upperLimit else newValue

e = Escuelas()
e.setIntValue(200)
print(e.intValue)
```

This sets the value to 100 (the upper limit) and not 200.